# Insert and Get with Entity Framework in single operation

Tags: entity-framework-6

Consider 2 tables `T1` & `T2` where table `T1` has a foreign key to the other table `T2`.
When I insert/update data into `T1`, I need to get data from corresponding row of `T2` based on the foreign key value that is being inserted into `T1`.

Can we achieve this with single EF operation? In my application I have several such situations.

I use `EF6 + .Net 4.6 + SQL Server 2016`

I have searched and it seems this is not possible so, for performance reasons (avoiding two calls to DB), I am moving my EF code to SP and EF is used just to call the SP.

Can someone tell me if there is a better way for this (because SPs are prone to maintenance issues)?

Note: SP may be against single-responsibility principle but given other priorities, that is what I want.

Comment: Where did you get that Sps are prone to maintenance issues? And who says it it's against SRP? And do you want to get the job done or worry over SRP?

Comment: If I completely depend on EF features, model changes are easily detected at compile time itself so I can correct those issues. In case of SPs, I will find errors only if I run them. SP itself is not against SRP but SP adds/inserts something and after that it returns something different so there is a possibility it "may be" against SRP. I want to avoid that discussion. I already mentioned, 'given other priorities...'

Comment: `for performance reasons (avoiding two calls to DB), I am moving my EF code to SP and EF is used just to call the SP.` have you done some benchmarking and noticed your application is not performing well because of that? Is that the bottleneck? Or you are doing premature optimization

Comment: If I were you i would do it with EF with 2 calls. If there is a performance issue, and it was narrowed down to that, I would then use an Sp. Like you said, you have priorities so if this is not the problem today, then don't worry about fixing it.